# passing value in partial view viewdatadictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/WO/Views/PartialContent/_FirstPage.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary {  { "WOID", WOID } })
```

In my Page i am accessing Partial view in the above way. 
I need to pass WOID(view data dictionary) value from query string, For that i am using following Code

```
@{
   var desc = Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("ID");
   Uri referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
   string[] query = referrer.Query.Split('=');
   int WOID = Convert.ToInt32(query[1]);
}
```

But the issue is this code is working in all browsers except I.E. i Need to Solve this problem.
  Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this you can have this value as part of you model and use that.That is the standard and recommeded way .

In your action method you can have these as parameter.Your query string value will get bind to this parameter

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod(int ID)
{
Model.WOID = WOID;
  // Other logic
  return View(Model)
}
```

Next step you can add this as a property to your view model or add it to ViewData dictionary and then access it in your partial view.

Comment: I need to get the value WOID from Query string.

Comment: yes the parameter of action method will have value from querystring.Only thing you need to make sure the name are exactly same